# googleVis datatype conversion in R does not seems to work

Tags: javascript, r, types, charts, googlevis

I have been working with 'googleVis' and R in order to produce a Line chart using Google charts APIs. 
On Google API's tutorial I found that data conversion in Javascript is used to determine if the axes will be "continuous"(using Numeric Javascript type) and "discrete" (using String).
I believe with googleVis is the same, since datatypes are derived from R. 
Problem is, in the following example (which I modified after taking it from the R demo function), the X axis values are equally spaced (hence, still discrete), despite they seem to be "Numeric"

```
library(googleVis)
df=data.frame(val1=c(10,13,100), val2=c(23,12,32))
Line <- gvisLineChart(df)
plot(Line)
```

Could someone please me help to understand this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**Full disclosure: I love the googleVis package.**

I see the same behavior you do, even after updating to the latest version of googleVis (not yet on CRAN). I don't know if this is a bug or not; the googleVis documentation for gvisLineChart *mentions* continuous data, but nothing I tried allows me to plot the X axis as numerical.

You can get clues as to what's happening when you change aspects of your code in generating googleVis charts and graphs if you right-click on the web page that gets displayed with the plot, and choose "View Page Source." This page is where the magic happens, and is the HTML output from the googleVis package.

The problematic line in this case is the one that reads "data.addColumn('string','val1');

In this line, the word 'string' should be 'number', and the val1 values should not be in quotes in the data section.

**You can get the results you want, though, by using gvisScatterChart instead:**

```
library(googleVis)
df=data.frame(val1=c(10,13,100), val2=c(23,12,32))
Line <- gvisScatterChart(df, options=list(lineWidth=2, pointSize=0))
plot(Line)
```

Comment: R version 3.0.0, googleVis 0.4.3. I got this: `data.addColumn('number','val1');`